# How do I make fog use S3 Reduced Redundancy Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm managing some images in my app using Carrierwave and I want the files uploaded to S3 to use Reduced Redundancy Storage instead of Standard. Carrierwave uses fog to talk to S3, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around for a while I ended up setting the following line in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```
config.fog_attributes = { 
  'x-amz-storage-class' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
}
```

What took me longest was finding the right attribute name and what value to send. This was a good resource: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html